# How to open the options menu programmatically?

Tags: android, button, menu, android-activity

I would like to open the optionsMenu programmatically without a click on the menu key from the user. How would I do that?

Answer (score 94):

Or just call [Activity.openOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29)?

Comment: Is is possible to execute this statement in oncreate() method of Activity?

Comment: @Vikas. Put it in onAttachedToWindow(), as described by Kovac below.

Comment: not working, I had custom view in actionbar, and on childview onClick I am calling open/close optionMenu, also with super.open/close
not working, any idea, where I am mistaking,

Comment: How  to implement this in a Fragment??

Answer (score 33):

Apparently, doing it in onCreate breaks app, since Activity's not yet attached to a window. If you do it like so:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    openOptionsMenu(); 
};
```

...it works.

Comment: Yes, it works. However, it would be better to have `super.onAttachedToWindow()` as the first line of the function.

Answer (score 16):

For developers using the new `Toolbar` class of the `Support Library`, this is how it's done:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
```

Comment: im doing this in an activity with a collapsing toolbar as well as a toolbar and it doesnt work4me no matter where I put it, plz help

Answer (score 11):

Put this line of code in your onResume(), this should help!

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
   public void run() { 
     openOptionsMenu(); 
   } 
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 9):

from an OnClickListener inside an activity called MainActivity:

```
MainActivity.this.openOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: Worked like a champ.  Android 4.4.2, API 19

Answer (score 4):

if using AppCompatActivity

```
getSupportActionBar().openOptionsMenu();
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to do it:

```
Activity.getWindow().openPanel(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL, event);
```

The `event` argument is a `KeyEvent` describing the key used to open the menu, which can modify how the menu is displayed based on the type of keyboard it came from.

Or... by simulating that the user has pressed the button:

```
IWindowManager wManager = IWindowManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService("window"));
KeyEvent kd = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SOFT_LEFT);
KeyEvent ku = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SOFT_LEFT);
wManager.injectKeyEvent(kd.isDown(), kd.getKeyCode(), kd.getRepeatCount(), kd.getDownTime(), kd.getEventTime(), true);
```

Comment: I think your answer is the best because openOptionsMenu() withh cause application crashing on HTC one and Sony Xperia Acro , while your solution avoids this point...So Thank yOu

Comment: IWindowManager is not a public part of the SDK. You did you get a reference to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside an your view, you can write

```
    ((Activity)getContext()).openOptionsMenu();
```

Answer (score -1):

After a long research and many tries, the only way seems to be simulating a `KeyEvent`. This makes the options menu appear:

```
BaseInputConnection mInputConnection = new BaseInputConnection( findViewById(R.id.main_content), true);
KeyEvent kd = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
KeyEvent ku = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU);
mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(kd);
mInputConnection.sendKeyEvent(ku);
```

Comment: what is main_content here

Answer (score -1):

For me, declaring `toolbar.showOverflowMenu()` in onClick is not worked. `openOptionsMenu()` also not worked for me. Instead of that the following way is worked for me,

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
            }
        }, 500);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
        }
    }, 100);
```