# Imitate ActionBar menu with ImageButton

Tags: android, android-layout

Does anyone know how I could use an `ImageButton` and imitate the popup of the corresponding menu? That is, to have the menu show up just below the button. Should I be using a context menu?

Basically, I'm trying to make the menu show up like below, except that I'm not using an ActionBar.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133318/how-to-open-the-options-menu-programmatically

Comment: @Naddy That just opens it as an options menu - not as a pop up menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are talking about [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu). If so, it can be done at the following way:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private PopupMenu mPopupMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        mPopupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, imageButton);
        MenuInflater menuInflater = mPopupMenu.getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, mPopupMenu.getMenu());
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPopupMenu.show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Result is the following:

[image: the following]