# Android: Open menu programmatically

Tags: android, android-menu

I've been trying to add a functionality to my android application such that when I click a button, menu listing should be visible:

Here is my code:

menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context="com.example.MainActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_onthego_sentence"
          android:title="settings"
          android:orderInCategory="100"
          app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

From the main activity, upon clicking a button, I do:

```
        button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View view )
            {
                runOnUiThread( new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        openOptionsMenu();
                    }
                } );
            }
        } );
```

What I need is:

[image]

As shown in the image, I'd like to see the menu is opened. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Look this thread may helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3133318/5241603

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
MainActivity.this.openOptionsMenu();
```

Then, check your toolbar if is this okay.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.acercade_activity);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        // MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            //case R.id.action_settings:
            //    return true;

            case R.id.perfil:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);



        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes this works if the MainActivity is extended by 'Activity' class, but strangely if it's extended by 'AppCompatActivity', it doesn't work. Any idea about that?

Comment: Check de new update, your problem  is the toolbar. @nick

Answer (score 4):

If you are using customized toolbar in your app, then the following way will be useful,

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
                }
            }, 500);
```

Comment: In toolbar case don't forget to inflate menu first. Then call 
```showOverflowMenu();```

Answer (score 2):

Hello Dear if you are using toolbar following code

```
toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
```

And other wise you can directly call

```
MainActivity.this.openOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: In toolbar case don't forget to **inflate menu** first. Then call ```showOverflowMenu();```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your menu layout:

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_settings"
android:orderInCategory="100"
android:title="Setting"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below solution It will be display click on the button  menu listing should be visible:

**res/menu/main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_changeLang"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Change Lang" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_color"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Select color" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_applist"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="App List" />
</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_changeLang:
            // Add your code
            break;
        case R.id.action_color:
            // Add your code
            break;
        case R.id.action_applist:
            // Add your code
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Try to use above solution. It will work for me

Answer (score 0):

Use Activity.openOptionsMenu() to open menu programmatically, but you may need to post delay to call it. like below

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        openOptionsMenu();
    }
}, 1000);
```

If you need to open sub menu automatically. you can call menu.performIdentifierAction after openOptionsMenu, like below

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        openOptionsMenu();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mainMenu.performIdentifierAction(R.id.submenu, 0);
            }
        }, 500);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Android Dev efficiency tools: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.trinea.android.developertools

Android Open Source Projects: https://p.codekk.com/