# How to Trigger onCreateOptionsMenu automatically

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, oncreateoptionsmenu

I want to show onCreateOptionsMenu which is on the right top side of the application. without touching on the three dots. what i am actually planing to do is, when the app runs for the first time i want show the menu items to user automatically, how can i do that [see the screenshot to get more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8Nyw.png)

```
    SharedPreferences preferences=  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if (!preferences.getBoolean("Time",false))
    {

     // code to trigger onCreateOptionsMenu

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing menu items ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Time",true);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: If you are searching for something that you'd like todo in code, it's good to search for _How to ... programmatically_ which yields - beside many stack overflow answers - this answer with many cases f.e. for AppCompat/Toolbar and the troubles of `onCreate`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133318/how-to-open-the-options-menu-programmatically and another thing, if you want to call an action for the UI (on UI Thread) Programmatically it may be good to checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850143/android-basics-running-code-in-the-ui-thread

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one single method `openOptionsMenu();`
call it in `onCreate` if you want it initially opened.

Comment: can i simply call openOptionsMenu(); to open the menu ??

Comment: its not opening anything

Answer (score 0):

If your MainActivity inherits from `Activity`, you can use `openOptionsMenu();`.
If you use `Toolbar`, then go for `toolbar.showOverflowMenu()`

From your question, As most of the Android mobile users are aware of the overflow/three-dot option, a demo may not be required. If you really feel that user should know about the overflow items, you can show user hints/direction for which many [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031488/android-popupwindow-with-tooltip-arrow) are available.