# Android studio: Activate options menu simultaneously with activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, menu

I have a main fragment. From there, I have a button that redirects to a new activity. In this activity, I have an options menu (on the toolbar). I want that options menu to automatically open with the activity. How do I do that?
Here's the code for the original fragment (the one which redirects to the new activity).

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.TirarFoto:
            Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    CameraActivity.class);
            startActivity(myintent);
            return false;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

and here is the "CameraActivity" menu code which I want to activate with the activity

```java
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, menu){
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_foto, menu);
   return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.addImage) {
        showImageImportDialog();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void showImageImportDialog() {
    String[] items = {"Camera", "Gallery"};
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Select image");
    dialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == 0) {
                if (!checkCameraPermission()) {
                    requestCameraPermission();
                } else {
                    pickCamera();
                }
            }
            if (which == 1) {
                if (!checkStoragePermission()) {
                    requestStoragePermission();
                } else {
                    pickGallery();

                }

            }
        }
    });
    dialog.create().show();
}
```

This is probably a silly question, but I'm new to this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open the options menu programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133318/how-to-open-the-options-menu-programmatically)

Comment: No. I've tried all the solutions.However, they don't always specify where to plug them in, so I don't really know if it's on the "onCreate" of CameraActivity or on the  "onMenuItemClick" of mainactivity