# How to dynamically display a context menu?

Tags: android, menu

I'm trying to dynamically display a context menu, such that when a user presses a key on physical keyboard, it should pop up the menu. (Target device has a numeric keypad, no menu key, no touch screen).

Not sure how to achieve this. I can get the menu object as a class variable in my activity, but thats as far as it goes.

```
private Menu mMenu;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_ops, menu);
    mMenu = menu;
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode==17){
        //Todo: Display mMenu
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: mMenu.popUp(); ?

Comment: @blackapps - its not a popup menu object, and that method doesn't exist in `Menu`. I see that `Menu` is an interface though, so if I can get direction on how to get the object which is implementing this interface,that includes such a method, that might help. thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133318/how-to-open-the-options-menu-programmatically

Comment: @blackapps perfect thanks